# Tidying messed up date-time cells from excel data dump

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCwPk.png)Hi guys, is there an efficiency way to tidy up the messed up date format in excel as shown in the image? I want to standardise them into the UK date-time format.

I am UK based and the data is pulled from a US platform. As you can see cells that have left-alignment are in UK format but those with right-alignment are in the US format. When I open Format Cells in Excel, those with UK format are categorised as 'General' but those in US format are categorised as 'Custom: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm'.

I tried date functions in excel but they don't work as expected.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just update entire column with format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm?

Comment: Hi pgSystemTester. Thanks for the answer. I tried. Nothing changed either.

Comment: You mean the left-aligned cells are "dd/mm/yyyy" and the right-aligned ones are "mm/dd/yyyy" and you want all of them formatted as "dd/mm/yyy"? I don't live in the UK nor the USA, hence the question.

Comment: Left-aligned cells are 'dd/mm/yy hh:mm', which is the UK format I want. 

Right-aligned cells are 'mm/dd/yy hh:mm', which is the US format I want to change. 

I want all the cells to be in the UK format 'dd/mm/yy hh:mm'.

Comment: Can you post as a google sheet or share the file on OneDrive?

Comment: The data is probably coming from a text/csv file. Do not **Open** the file.  Instead **Import** the file using Power Query or the Legacy import wizard, and designate that column as Date with format of the imported data (most likely MDY from your description). Oh, and your dates that appear to be real dates are probably incorrect anyway.  After you do that, they will be imported as "real" dates, and you will be able to format them however you want.

Comment: I think your system might be set to display dates in the US format. Press Win+R and type `intl.cpl`, hit Enter and check the date format first.

Comment: And if these settings are correct, then just select the cells and set the format to Date or Short Date and tell me what happens.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer. Here is the OneDrive share link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnLz3wyIfbxTgsw5_j-58qo-_SvddQ?e=aRyCeB

My system is set as displaying UK dates. The file is not text/csv, it's xls.

Comment: @B.. Most likely, the source of that Excel file was a CSV.  Any chance of getting back to the original?  If not, it is likely that the dates that show as "real" dates were converted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spreadsheet you shared the dates are interpreted as month/day/year. Beware. In fact, the reason why some dates are not interpreted as dates is that they begin with a number > 12, so clearly Excel is expecting the month to come first.

Anyway, fill a second column with this formula:

```
=IF(ISNONTEXT(B3),B3,DATE(MID(B3,7,4),MID(B3,4,2),MID(B3,1,2))+TIME(MID(B3,12,2),MID(B3,15,2),0))
```

and that should give you all your dates represented as actual dates, not text strings. Then if you want to copy them, select the second column, copy and **paste as values** (there's a Paste Special option, or Ctrl+Alt+V).

Comment: Thanks vpprof. Would you mind clarifying your first statement? How to know the interpretation of the dates in any sheet? The shared sheet contains both the UK and the US formatting dates. That's why I don't quite get your saying 'you shared the dates are interpreted as month/day/year'. Does that mean I have to first transform them into a number in order to know the dates interpretation? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, the left alignment tells you that Excel just thinks the cells contain text, as numbers and dates are aligned to the right. That's the least tech-savvy way of telling. When I click on on of the right-aligned cells and change the format to Long Date, "12/6/2020" shows up as "Sunday, December 6, 2020". That's how I know that Excel wants the month to go first.

Comment: Secondly, a date is internally represented as a number, e.g. #1900-01-01# is 1, #1900-01-02# is 2 and so on. You can see this if you click on any of the right-aligned dates and change the format to General or Numeric. 
What happens when you paste text that looks like a date is that Excel just uses the default system date format to interpret this text, and then calculates the date-number, stores that number in the cell, changes the cell format to Date. So if 12/06/2020 got interpreted as December, that's why I guess your system is set to display mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy.